# Enable automatic syntax highlighting for JavaScript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The question [lightning:navigation to record edit page not working when there is an record update before it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/254741/38716) is tagged [javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) but syntax highlighting was not applied to the code block. I [suggested an edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/105816) introducing an HTML comment `<!-- language: lang-js -->` which enables this, but it's much quicker if this is done on tag level instead.

Can one of the ♦ moderators please enable automatic syntax highlighting for this tag (the setting is configurable on [this page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/javascript/info))? It's active for other tags already, e.g. [visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/visualforce/info), where you see the following at the bottom:

> Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)): lang-xml

Answer (score 4):

I've updated it.

[image: Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-js]